# Upgrade Jetty version to 9.4.8 in build.gradle

Tags: gradle, gretty

I am currently using the following gretty configuration in build.gradle:

```
gretty {
  servletContainer = 'jetty9'
}
```

I want to upgrade the jetty version to 9.4.8.
From a quick search I found that jetty9 stands for the version Jetty 9.2.22.v20170606 (from: http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Switching-between-servlet-containers.html). I couldn't anything on how to upgrade to jetty version 9.4.8. Could someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, from this [doc](http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Gretty-configuration.html), you can configure gretty to use `'jetty9.4' (jdk 8 only)` instead of `jetty9`.

In the latest v2.0.0 release, plugin will work with `jetty9` of `9.2.22.v20170606` and `jetty9.4` of `v9.4.6.v20170531`, respectively.([ref](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/blob/28d24aa03e59c190dc19f97f9276754badebae03/gradle.properties))

```
jetty9_version=9.2.22.v20170606
jetty94_version=9.4.6.v20170531
```

You can PR for [jetty94_version](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/blob/28d24aa03e59c190dc19f97f9276754badebae03/gradle.properties#L17).

[updated]

I have created a sample project using Spring MVC with Jetty 9.4.8 particularly in [this commit](https://github.com/chenrui333/so-49671719/commit/669ef06f400869bd7061d9143e3cd7c6be3b2714).

[edit note]

Please use '**jetty9.4**' (instead of 'jetty94') - Refer to this [github comment](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/issues/371#issuecomment-310216661) for more info

Comment: jetty94 is version 9.4.6. I have a requirement to upgrade to 9.4.8. is that not possible..

Comment: You can use artifact host like Nexus to host your own fork of the plugin, then you can update properties and push a new version there.

Comment: Another solution is to PR the version properties and go with the official plugin release (this may take some time)

Comment: i tried giving servletContainer='jetty9.4' in build.gradle and overridden the property in gradle.properties  jetty94Version=9.4.8.v20171121. It gave me the error 'Unsupported servlet container: jetty9.4'...So I kept servletContainer='jetty9' and added the property jetty9Version=9.4.8.v20171121... is this okay..will it pick up the 9.4 version given in gradle.properties?

Comment: you cannot override the gradle.properties to inject the new version, that has to come from the plugin itself.

Comment: tried that because this page says so: http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Overriding-servlet-container-versions.html

Comment: @SusannaM Please check with my sample setup in this commit, https://github.com/chenrui333/so-49671719/commit/669ef06f400869bd7061d9143e3cd7c6be3b2714

Comment: Above was helpful. Could you please post it as an answer so that i Could accept it