# Problem starting web application from eclipse and how to upgrade jetty to 9.4.20 in build.gradle

Tags: gradle, jetty, build.gradle, jetty-9, gretty

**Project:** Gradle web project

**IDE:** Eclipse

**JAVA VERSION:**

```
 java version "1.8.0_202"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)
```

**Build Tool:** Gradle

**Web Server:** Jetty 9.4.20.v20190813

Currently, the gretty configuration in build.gradle is as below,

```
gretty {
  servletContainer = 'jetty9'
}
```

I have two things to confirm:

1) I came to know that jetty9 will uses jetty 9.2.22.v20170606 and even jetty9.4 will use 9.4.6.v20170531 which I confirmed running web application from eclipse. Referred from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49676985/11733763

I need to use jetty 9.4.20.v20190813 in my development environment since we upgraded the jetty server to 9.4.20.v20190813. How could this be achieved?

2) I have recently upgraded **Jersey libraries to 2.29.1** and **Jackson libraries to 2.10.0**.

Jersey libs

```
jersey-client.jar
jersey-common.jar
jersey-container-servlet.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
jersey-entity-filtering-2.29.1.jar
jersey-hk2.jar
jersey-media-jaxb.jar
jersey-media-json-jackson-2.29.1.jar
jersey-media-multipart-2.29.1.jar
jersey-server.jar
```

Jackson libs

```
jackson-annotations-2.10.0.jar
jackson-core-2.10.0.jar
jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar
jackson-jaxrs-base-2.10.0.jar
jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.10.0.jar
jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.10.0.jar
```

When I run web application from eclipse, I face below exception

Stack trace

```
Working Directory: E:\USW\eclipse-workspace\mywebapp
Gradle User Home: C:\Users\dhandapa-2\.gradle
Gradle Distribution: Gradle wrapper from target build
Gradle Version: 4.10.2
Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: false
Offline Mode Enabled: false
Gradle Tasks: appRunDebug

> Task :prepareInplaceWebAppFolder NO-SOURCE
> Task :createInplaceWebAppFolder
> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :prepareInplaceWebAppClasses
> Task :prepareInplaceWebApp
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
> Task :appRunDebug

18:06:46 WARN  Failed startup of context o.a.g.JettyWebAppContext@e041f0c{/nts,file:/E:/USW/eclipse-workspace/nts/build/inplaceWebapp/,STARTING}
org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException: Multiple exceptions
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations(AnnotationConfiguration.java:537) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:448) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:479) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1337) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741) ~[jetty-server-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyWebAppContext.super$10$doStart(JettyWebAppContext.groovy) [gretty-runner-jetty9-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:152) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.groovy:44) [gretty-runner-jetty9-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) [jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) [jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) [jetty-server-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:163) [jetty-server-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) [jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387) [jetty-server-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) [jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) [jetty-server-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354) [jetty-server-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle$start$0.call(Unknown Source) [jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyServerManager.startServer(JettyServerManager.groovy:45) [gretty-runner-jetty-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.ServerManager$startServer$0.call(Unknown Source) [gretty-runner-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.run(Runner.groovy:117) [gretty-runner-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.main(Runner.groovy:44) [gretty-runner-2.0.0.jar:na]
    Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:/E:/USW/eclipse-workspace/libs/jackson-core-2.10.0.jar
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:913) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:831) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:164) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:549) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) ~[jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) ~[jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:973)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:/E:/USW/eclipse-workspace/libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.10.0.jar
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:913) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:831) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:164) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:549) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) ~[jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) ~[jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:973)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:/E:/USW/eclipse-workspace/libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.10.0.jar
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:913) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:831) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:164) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:549) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) ~[jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) ~[jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:973)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:/E:/USW/eclipse-workspace/libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.10.0.jar
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:913) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:831) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:164) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:549) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) ~[jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) ~[jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:973)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:/E:/USW/eclipse-workspace/libs/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:913) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:831) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:164) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:549) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) ~[jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) ~[jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:973)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:/E:/USW/eclipse-workspace/libs/jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:913) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:831) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:164) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:549) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) ~[jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) ~[jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:973)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException: Multiple exceptions
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:899) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:831) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:164) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:549) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) ~[jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) ~[jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/11/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/jsr166/SubmissionPublisher$2.class from jar file:/E:/USW/eclipse-workspace/libs/jersey-common.jar
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:913)
            ... 6 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:973)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909)
            ... 6 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/11/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/jsr166/SubmissionPublisher$3.class from jar file:/E:/USW/eclipse-workspace/libs/jersey-common.jar
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:913)
            ... 6 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:973)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909)
            ... 6 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/11/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/jsr166/SubmissionPublisher$4.class from jar file:/E:/USW/eclipse-workspace/libs/jersey-common.jar
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:913)
            ... 6 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:973)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909)
            ... 6 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/11/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/jsr166/SubmissionPublisher$5.class from jar file:/E:/USW/eclipse-workspace/libs/jersey-common.jar
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:913)
            ... 6 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:973)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909)
            ... 6 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/11/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/jsr166/SubmissionPublisher$6.class from jar file:/E:/USW/eclipse-workspace/libs/jersey-common.jar
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:913)
            ... 6 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:973)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909)
            ... 6 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/11/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/jsr166/SubmissionPublisher.class from jar file:/E:/USW/eclipse-workspace/libs/jersey-common.jar
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:913)
            ... 6 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:973)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909)
            ... 6 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/11/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/jsr166/SubmissionPublisherFactory.class from jar file:/E:/USW/eclipse-workspace/libs/jersey-common.jar
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:913)
            ... 6 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:973)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909)
            ... 6 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/11/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/jsr166/SubmissionPublisher$1.class from jar file:/E:/USW/eclipse-workspace/libs/jersey-common.jar
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:913)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:973)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: Timeout scanning annotations
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations(AnnotationConfiguration.java:578) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
        ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:/E:/USW/eclipse-workspace/libs/jackson-annotations-2.10.0.jar
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:913) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:831) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:164) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:549) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) ~[jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) ~[jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[asm-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[asm-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[asm-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:973) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
18:06:52 INFO  Jetty 9.2.22.v20170606 started and listening on port 8080
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no servlet container to use Jetty 9.4.20.v20190813 but we can override jetty9.4 in gradle.properties file. Refer this [link](https://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Switching-between-servlet-containers.html) for more details.